# Replace negative values in a row based on conditions with grouping and conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like this,

```
Industry = c("Industry1", "Industry1", "Industry1", "Industry2", "Industry2", "Industry3")
calc = c(-1.2345, 67890, 45678, -9.86544, 32456, 56789)
cy = c(0, 2019, 2017, 2016, 0, 2015)
py = c(0, 2018, 2016, 2015, 0, 2014)

data = data.frame(Industry, calc, cy, py, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to replace the negative values in calc column when cy = 0 and py = 0 by calculating the mean of calc column with grouping according to the industry. I have tried the following,

```
data = data %>% 
  group_by("Industry") %>% 
  mutate(calc = ifelse(cy == 0 & py == 0, summarise(calc = mean(calc)), calc))
```

But this isn't working. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: your `data` shows this error `Error in data.frame(Industry, calc, cy, py, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 7`

Comment: I've rectified it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may also use `replace`

```r
Industry = c("Industry1", "Industry1", "Industry1", "Industry2", "Industry2", "Industry3")
calc = c(-1.2345, 67890, 45678, -9.86544, 32456, 56789)
cy = c(0, 2019, 2017, 2016, 0, 2015)
py = c(0, 2018, 2016, 2015, 0, 2014)

data = data.frame(Industry, calc, cy, py, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)

data %>% group_by(Industry) %>%
  mutate(calc = replace(calc, calc <0 & cy == 0 & py == 0, mean(calc[calc >= 0])))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Industry [3]
#>   Industry      calc    cy    py
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Industry1 56784        0     0
#> 2 Industry1 67890     2019  2018
#> 3 Industry1 45678     2017  2016
#> 4 Industry2    -9.87  2016  2015
#> 5 Industry2 32456        0     0
#> 6 Industry3 56789     2015  2014
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can just mutate directly without `summarise()`.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Industry) %>% 
  mutate(
    calc = if_else(calc < 0 & cy == 0 & py == 0, mean(calc[calc > 0]), calc)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   Industry      calc    cy    py
#   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Industry1 56784        0     0
# 2 Industry1 67890     2019  2018
# 3 Industry1 45678     2017  2016
# 4 Industry2    -9.87  2016  2015
# 5 Industry2 32456        0     0
# 6 Industry3 56789     2015  2014
```

Comment: This way of applying mean includes mean calculation like this. For example, lets consider Industry1, the calculation is like this (-1.2345+67890+45678)/3 = 37856. Instead, I want to exclude py = 0 and cy = 0 value in calc while calculating mean, like this (67890 + 45678)/2 = 56784. Is it possible to do this using R?

Comment: Yes, you can subset `calc[calc > 0]` before computing the mean value. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ok just by adding one more condition it works! Thank you Zaw!